# Particular PC not running code

Tags: 14.04, usb, xubuntu, serial-port

I'm working on USB the code which i'm using usb cdc serial is not running on the PC which i'm using  is ubuntu 14.04.In other PC's the code is running fine.I changed the compiler and test with all backup codes.Still it's not working .     `

1. The CDCDSerialDriver_GetControlLineState () is always Zero in the pc
   which i'm using. There Serial port is not getting ON

Why it is happening?

Comment: Check whether there are not conflicting drivers with cdc driver. If yes, blacklist them.

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: run lsmod command on both machines and compare the output.

Comment: Can u give an explanation for this, How to do?

Comment: open terminal application and type lsmod and hit enter.

Comment: Then what i need to do the packages are entirely different.. which i need to look at?

Comment: The lsmod command outputs a list of loaded kernel modules, on the one of your computers there might be a conflict between two USB drivers. When two USB kernel modules want to use same device (serial USB), then you need blacklist one in order to make the second to work. Edit your question and paste the two lsmod outputs in your question - use code syntax.